# Spring MVC Controller for non-submit actions

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We have 2 spring modules, I have no control on module1, click action on a link in module1 redirects to URL in module2 and also sends url query strings, So capturing query strings process B.L and display results back in the same page. I don't have a submit action at all, But I see onSubmit() examples in spring mvc. How to handle non-submit actions? i appreciate your help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

By "non-submit actions", do you mean using GET HTTP method ?

If so, then with a basic `@RequestMapping` (or more restrictively `@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)`) annotated method in a `@Controller`, you can handle such actions... or are you using pre-2.5 versions of spring-mvc ?

Comment: thnx4reply. I hv 2 display results grabing URL query strings,URL was customized as http://ip:port/xx.htm?param1<value1>&param2<value2>..
@RequestMapping(value="/xx.htm?param1<value1>&param2<value2>......", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView processRequest(@PathVariable String param1,
    @PathVariable String param2, ..)) {
 DomainObject d = new DomainObject();
 d.setValue1(param1);
 ..
 results = service.findByxx(d);
 return new ModelAndView("display.jsp", "results", results); }
Plz corrent me if i am doing wrong.
Thank you

Comment: the query string of the mapped path must not be passed in; check the documentation here about parameters: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-params-and-headers . Otherwise it seems ok - maybe you can avoid giving a view name with the ".jsp" suffix (which may be handled by the viewResolver), see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver-resolver